From Eagle to Altium : Migrating Libraries
Seems there are some people here running Altium.
I am from a small company and we are using Eagle (Standalone Version not the one in Fusion).
We are planing to switcht to Altium, so I am running now a trial Version of Altium.
Main reason for the switch is, Eagle libs are a pain if several people are working on them.
So now I am figuring out what would be the best way to migrate those libs to Altium to have a neat and healty library monitored in Altium365.
Altium has an Eagle Importer which works kinda good but especially on IC's it gets sometimes crazy.
Also I can't wrap my Head around what an Altium Library should look like in terms of colloborating.
For instance: In Eagle it is common to use one Footprint for several, different Value Resistors. Is this also the best practice in Altium? Or is it beneficial to have a Component for every Value?
So much questions for me - does anyone have some resources on my topic - especially on working in small Teams with Altium coming from a different CAD?
Lukas

Can you use library.io in the Standalone Version of Eagle? That's been working pretty well for us across accounts

The choice of component footprint per value or one per type is an individual choice and Altium will accommodate both. If you tend to use 'generic' parts and don't put a lot of value in renderings of the PCB for documentation, then the choice will be the 2nd option. If you want to generate perfect no-edit BOMs then you need to have the actual manufacturer(s) and part numbers for each value.
Library management is complex enough that Altium has a specific training course for it. The person I sent there seemed to think it worthwhile (it was in-person at the time)- at the time there was several active seats, so similar to your situation.
